# How to convert a software shop to TDD?

Tags: tdd

I would really love to push for TDD development inside the shop I'm working in. Lots of the seniors over there didn't work with unit testing or did unit testing that was hitting the database.

I would love to bring some good arguments, books for training, possible coach to ease the transition.

Comment: Any more suggestions? Books? Coaches? Weasel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found that it is often very hard to push TDD from the developer up. What I tend to do is talk about the benefits of TDD as much as possible and wherever possible, introduce elements of TDD myself bit by bit.

If they don't mind, start a new project with unit tests in it (managers seldom mind more test coverage) and start developing that way yourself. Slowly show the rest of your team the benefits and try to win some converts. Once you have a few other developers on your side, start pushing management for some training.

You could also offer to run some lunch-n-learns about it for the other developers. Teaching is the best way of learning and your will hopefully gain allies. If you are lucky, you can talk your boss into buying the pizza for the lunch-n-learn and everyone benefits.

Answer (score 3):

Like Rob P said - I also found that preaching ended me with a hoarse voice and no one listening.  I got results faster and more widespread by doing it and keeping that part visible.  Be open to questioning and don't force it.  Encourage and praise but don't preach.

Combine it with publishing the results of your testing- and have that automated - you can send out an email perhaps.  You want many subtle reminders to show people how good your method is.

Answer (score 3):

I think a good way to sneak in TDD principals into an existing product is to start writing unit tests for bugs.  This way you slowly start to build up a set of unit tests for regression testing which become an integral part of the project, especially if you can get them run as part of your build process.

The only hurdle will be the existing code might be resistant to testing, but that's just another excuse to do some refactoring.

Once people start to realise the benefits the momentum will grow, but you need to pioneer the way.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't tell you what will work, I can tell you some things that definitely will not work and should be avoided:

**I'll write the code, you write the test**

This always comes up at first.  People assume that since you're so gung-ho about testing, you should be the one writing the tests.  This doesn't work at all and misses the whole point.

**You wrote the test that's breaking, so you have to fix it.**

If you start writing tests for your code, inevitably someone else will break those tests.  Then, if you ask them to fix it, they'll often say it's your responsibility.  This isn't necessarily them being a jerk, it could just be that they don't understand the process.  This is where you'll need management backup.

**I'll just start, and everyone will follow.**

Like others have said, TDD without management support is very hard.  If there are any devs who don't "drink the Cool-Aid" then they will constantly be breaking your tests and not caring.  If you can't make them believe, then you need management telling them it's their job.

What finally brought me around was watching a project collapse due to too many bugs.  It convinced me that I was doing something fundamentally wrong.  A little research brought me to automated testing, and with a little determination I taught myself the basics.  Perhaps talking to your fellow devs about similar projects (we all have at least one...) will help them realize that they might want to try something new.

Answer (score 2):

**Lead by example**:

- use TDD on all the code you write
- show them the benefits as soon as you have the opportunity (regression detected by the unit test or incident recreated in your unit testing environment)
- deliver "clean code that works"
- propose your assistance to others
- don't be dogmatic - TDD is not silver bullet
- make your unit tests visible: they should compile along with the code they test

Answer (score 1):

If the project doesn't have enough unit tests, you can point out bugs in the issue database that would probably have been avoided if there had been unit tests.

As for pushing TDD, or some other code religion, don't bother.

For some people (and some types of code), TDD is great. Some people don't work that way, and don't benefit from test-first. As long as they don't avoid testing altogether, I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 0):

A great challenge with TDD that is brought in "bottom up" is that, when push comes to shove (as it inevitably does when a deadline approaches), management is going to over-ride the emphasis on tests: "We can't afford to test! We have to finish the project!"

Of course, this is the very situation (deadline looming, significant backlog, progress not on track with promises, leading to rapidly shifting priorities and tasks) where the benefits of TDD really kick in. Management over-rides it, the project / iteration starts to come apart in the same-old same-old, and management looks back and says "We tried TDD and it didn't help at all."